# return false does not work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, onsubmit

I came across a weird little problem. After searching around to fix the refreshing of a page after a form submit, I found that you could use 'return false'. I was happy to see that it worked in FF, but when I tried in IE... it still refreshed the page.

This is the important part of the code:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); showAddress(this.address.value); return false">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><h3>address:</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" name="address" value="" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><button type="submit" value="Zoek!">Zoek!</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

How can I make sure it doesn't refresh in IE?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I changed it now, so that I am no longer using a form. Instead I use the button's onclick event. Thanks to Shin for pointing out my error.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td><h3>address:</h3></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="text" size="60" name="address" value="" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><button type="submit" onclick="showAddress(this.value); value="Zoek!">Zoek!</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call all the functions in on click functions

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that it doesn't pass the parameter to my javascript that I'm using. I tried it like this: button onclick="showAddress(this.address.value);" but that doesn't do anything, since it doesn't pass the parameter

Comment: That is a javascript error,You can only use onclick="showAddress(this.value);"

Comment: You sir, made my day :D now everything works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the preventDefault() on the onclick event for the submit button.

Comment: I tried this, but this didn't really work for me. The page still refreshes. thanks though ^^

Answer (score 0):

handle onclick event of button in JS and add following lines in JS handler

```
//e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.returnValue = false;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, could be that I'm doing something wrong though. This is what I do: function noRefresh(){
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = false;
 } and I call that function at the onclick